# LESS CSS with Assetic and Symfony 3 less assetic.ERROR: The template "::base.html.twig" contains an error: There is no "less" filter

Tags: symfony, less, assetic

I am trying to use LESS in symfony3. 
I have already installed AsseticBundle.

I was going through this tutorial.

http://kiwwito.com/less-css-with-assetic-and-symfony-2/

But my config.yml looks a little bit different.

```
assetic:
    filters:
        less:
            node: /usr/bin/node
            node_paths: [/usr/local/lib/node_modules]
```

There is no .node_libraries in my file system.

My base.html.twig

```
{% stylesheets filter='less' output='css/compiled-main.css' '@MyBundle/Resources/public/less/*'%}
    <link href="" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

After reloading the page i got error.

```
An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("There is no "less" filter.") in "base.html.twig".
```

I have got Symfony 3.2.8.

Comment: may be cash clear php bin/console c:c && php bin/console c:c --env=prod

Comment: no, did not help

Comment: may be your node is in /usr/share/node, have a look with whereis node command line

Comment: paths are correct

Comment: .node_libraries shall be hidden in your $HOME directory /home/YourUserName/.node_libraries I think

Comment: give us some feedback

Comment: it seems that i dont have .node_libraries directory in my file system at all

Comment: Do you have another Assetic block within your config.yml?